# Detect SO missing at runtime

Tags: c++, qt5, shared-libraries

I have writing a Qt5/C++ program in Linux which tries to use some library functions.  If that library is not installed, then the user sees warnings on stderr as follows:

```
qt.canbus.plugins.socketcan: Cannot load library socketcan: (socketcan: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
qt.canbus.plugins.socketcan: Cannot load library libsocketcan, some functionality will not be available.
```

I know the solution is to install the library, but I would like my code to be able to detect the missing library and shutdown gracefully.  Is this possible in standard C++ or Qt5 ?

Comment: Are you familar with [`dlopen(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), how it works, and know how to use it?

Comment: `QPluginLoader` is probably the way to go with Qt